# #1044 - access denied for user 'id9605813_band'@'%' to database 'information_schema'

Tags: mysql

I tried to move my data base from the `localhost` of `phpmyadmin` to another `phpmyadmin` using a free webhost,"000webhost" to be precise.

I tried just some simple code

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `price` double(9,2) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `stock` int(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and the only thing i get is this:

> 1044 - Access denied for user 'id9605813_band'@'% to database 'information_schema'

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you show us how you are connecting to the database?

Comment: I am using a db.php with all the right passwords names etc. I think

Comment: Could you show the connect statement? And could you show the user table from your database (`SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;`), and the permissions of your user (`SHOW GRANTS FOR 'id9605813_band'@'%'`)?  Either you have an error in what you're passing to the connect statement, or your user really doesn't have permission to access the database.

Comment: Yeah I think I found my mistake I didn't have the permission to do such a thing and I skipped a whole step to importing my code,thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user doesn't have the correct user permissions to create edits/writes to the respective database.

Comment: This doesn't help in any way, you just stated the obvious.